# can't get ERC721 transferFrom() to work

Tags: erc-721, openzeppelin, transferfrom

I'm using `pragma solidity 0.8.15;` and hardhat.

Trying to send an `ERC721` using `transferFrom()`, from an EOA to a contract. I did `approve(address to, uint256 tokenId)` first.
But the transfer is still not going through.

These are my functions:

`bNote.approve(address(this), csd.loanId);`

`IPromissoryNote(address(bNote)).transferFrom(seller, address(this),  csd.loanId);`

I am passing `IPromissoryNote _bNote` in the constructor like so:

```
    constructor(
        ILendingPoolAddressesProvider _addressesProvider,
        IPromissoryNote _bNote
        ) {
        ADDRESSES_PROVIDER = _addressesProvider;
        LENDING_POOL = ILendingPool(_addressesProvider.getLendingPool());

        owner = msg.sender;

        bNote = _bNote;
    }
```

```
contract PromissoryNote is
    Context,
    AccessControlEnumerable,
    ERC721Enumerable,
    ERC721Pausable,
    ERC721Permit,
    IPromissoryNote
```

Many thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Figured it out. I needed to add ERC721Receiver to my contract and the onERC721Received function.